# how to remove certain words in inputbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

In my form i have 13 input box in my form ,I allow user to type only text and number using following script

### **FILTER INPUT TEXT**

```
$(function() {//<-- wrapped here
                $('.restrict').on('input', function() {
                    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9@]/g, ''); //<-- replace all other than given set of values
                });
            });
```

Above script allows only text from a-z, number only

My question is i need to filter certain words in input box before saving it to database

**Eg:** if user enters `*adult* content` in input box i need to filter the word `adult` and save only `content` to database

Can some one please help me

and can some one help me where do i find list of bad words

Comment: Do you have a list of restricted words?

Comment: [Good luck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) with that.

Comment: @MarcB I hear Scunthorpe is a rough town.

Comment: If you allow @, shouldn't you also allow dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use `replace()`

have a look at @BBonifield answer for multiple words

http://jsfiddle.net/6hxspv14/2/

```
$(function(){

    var timer = 0;
    var sensor_word = ['adult', 'porn', 'sex'];

    $('.restrict').on('keyup', function(){

        clearTimeout(timer);
        var new_value = this.value;
        var new_sensor = $('.restrict').val();

        $.each(sensor_word, function (idx, word) {
          new_sensor = new_sensor.replace(word, '***');
        }); 

        timer = setTimeout(function(){
             $('#result').text( new_sensor );
        }, 0);

    });

    $('.restrict').on('keydown', function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });


});
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? Because I tried it in codepen and it did not work

Comment: what if i need to replace more than 5 or 6 words how do i do that

Comment: @tonoslfx since i already have `onkeyup="validate();` will the above code work

Comment: @creator yea should do!

Comment: @tonoslfx i found a bug can you help me when i type `se x` in input box filter does't works

Comment: @creator you can add any words you want to sensor into `sensor_word` array

Comment: @tonoslfx thanks it works i just added `se x` to sensor word list thans for helping me and can you please help me were do i find BAD WORDS

Comment: @tonoslfx while saving input text to `SQL` it doest filter words

Answer (score 3):

If it's a large number of words you need to filter, you're probably better off moving that logic from JS to PHP. Also, with JavaScript I can still manipulate the POST request to get bad words into your database.

- [How do you implement a good profanity filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273516/how-do-you-implement-a-good-profanity-filter)
- [Filter a set of bad words out of a PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141233/filter-a-set-of-bad-words-out-of-a-php-array)
- [filtering bad words from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852809/filtering-bad-words-from-text)
- [How do I replace bad words with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020451/how-do-i-replace-bad-words-with-php)

Comment: is there a way to remove bad words in `html input box`

Comment: With PHP you'd fetch the input from $_POST and then take out the bad words. If you want the input to be filtered in the browser, as soon as (or while) the words are entered, you'd have to use JavaScript. You marked the question with the PHP tag and you're storing the input in a database so I assumed the data would be processed by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it a few different ways, but one simple way would be to simply remove all the words that you don't want to include whenever the user leaves the field.

```
var badWords = [ 'adult', 'crap' ];
$(':input').on('blur', function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $.each(badWords, function(idx, word){
    value = value.replace(word, '');
  });
  $(this).val( value);
});
```

Comment: how to link this with input box i need to use this method `onkeyup="validate();` or what??

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() { 
    $('.restrict').on('input', function() {

        var value = this.value;
        var isAdultContent = ( value.match( /^\W*adult\W+/ ) || [] ).length;
        var content = value.replace( /^\W*adult\W+/, '' );

        if( isAdultContent ){
            //...
        }
        else{
            //...
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following might also be useful, check if value is in array using $.inArray :

```
$(function() {
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var badwords = ["doodoo", "peepee"];
    var inputVal = $('.restrict').val();

    if ($.inArray(inputVal, badwords) > -1) {  // returns -1 if value not in array
        $('.restrict').val('');   // empties input box if swear word is found
    }
    });
});
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jxvvqraL/