# How to check if a string of text contains a bad word?

Tags: php

I have written this script for filtering bad words but I want to use (if statement) which if found in text $bad words echo out (" bad text ") and if didn't found echo out (" clean text "):

```
function badWords($text){
$bad = array('dirty','butt','lips');
//echo out
$rep = array('***','***','***');

for ($i=0; $i < count($bad); $i++){
    $text = str_replace($bad[$i], $rep[$i], $text);
}
echo $text;
}

//the text
$text = " this is a dirty text test no butt here and no lips ";

badWords($text);
```

Comment: What happens currently? You shouldnt need to iterate, `str_replace` takes arrays.

Comment: You can compare the output of your `str_replace` to the original text. If it's different, there's things that have been replaced.

Comment: yes i know actually this is my first code i tried to replace it works but now i want to use ( if ) found in $text var $bad words echo out something

Comment: So are you asking how to use an `if`, or what?

Comment: yes i ask how to use if in this code i mean if found in $text a $bad words do something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter a set of bad words out of a PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141233/filter-a-set-of-bad-words-out-of-a-php-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
function badWords($text){
    $bad = array('dirty','butt','lips');
    $rep = array('***','***','***');
    $text = str_replace($bad, $rep, $text);
    return $text;
}

//the text
$text = " this is a dirty text test no butt here and no lips ";

if ($text != badWords($text)){
    echo " bad text ";
} else {
    echo " clean text ";
}
```

I just returned the new text and compare both, I also improved your code by passing the arrays to the `str_replace` function since it's able to use them direcly. (And removed spaces...)

As pointed out in the comments by @Naumov the array with *** could be remove... (If it is always three asterisks...)

Comment: sure it will works i'll try it thank you guys <3 <3 <3 <3

Comment: @DocTor I just improved the answer/code. Take another look :)

Comment: Good answer, however I think the OP's goal may be to show the asterisks. If so, then they can add `echo badWords($text);` just above the `if()` statement (as an option).

Comment: Yes good answer but you can simple use `return str_replace($bad, '***', $text);`  and your answer replase `butter` on `***re` and not work on anytime

Comment: @Rodrigo Graça ur code works really thank you very much you helped me <3 that what i looking for

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code that does what you want in a better way

```
function badWords($text)
{
    $bad = array('dirty','butt','lips');

    for ($i=0; $i < count($bad); $i++)
    {
        $position = strpos($text, $bad[$i]);
        while($position !== false)//if text contains a bad word
        {
            for($j=$position; $j<$position+strlen($bad[$i]); $j++)
                $text[$j]='*';
            $position = strpos($text, $bad[$i]);
        }
    }
    echo $text;
}


$text = " this is a dirty text test no butt here and no lips ";
badWords($text);
```

Output is 
`this is a ***** text test no **** here and no ****`

This will replace all bad words with * and keep their length. The way it works is, you first loop trough all the bad words, and check whether `strpos` is false. If it's false, then the text does not contain the bad word. If it's not false, then `strpos` will return the position of the first letter of the bad word in your `$text`. You then loop from that first position until the last position, which is the length of the bad word, and replace each character with `*`.

Comment: It's bad way replace by for words if you can use `str_replace` you use string as array yes in  C and C++ string this array chars, but in php, you use 2 for's....

Comment: This will not filter multiple words. Ie dirty dirty will be ***** dirty

Answer (score 0):

strpos will allow you to determine if a string contains a word. Try this example.

```
$containsBad = false;

for ($i=0; $i < count($bad); $i++){
    $pos = strpos($text, $bad[$i]);

    if ($pos !== false) {
        $containsBad = true;

        break;
    }
}

if ($containsBad) {
    // the text contains a bad word
}
```

Comment: This mwpeans oprocessing the text twice

Comment: Yes. It wasn't clear what the OP was trying to accomplish.

Comment: I wrote my answer based on checking if the string contains a bad word (which is what the OP appeared to be asking how to do).

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the last argument of str_replace which is the count

```
function badWords($text){

$totalReplacements = 0;
$count = 0;
$bad = array('dirty','butt','lips');
//echo out
$rep = array('***','***','***');


for ($i=0; $i < count($bad); $i++){

    $text = str_replace($bad[$i], $rep[$i], $text, $count);

    $totalReplacements += $count;

}

echo $text;

if ($totalReplacements > 0){
    echo "Bad";
} else {
    echo "Good";
}

}
```

as a side note, If you indent your code you will get much more readable and maintainable code

EDIT,

Some cleaner code with the stars generated

```
<?php
function badWords($text)
{
    $count = 0;
    $bad = array_flip([
        'dirty',
        'butt',
        'lips',
    ]);

    array_walk(
        $bad,
        function (&$value, $key)
        {
            $value = str_repeat('*', strlen($key));
        }
    );
    $text = str_replace(array_keys($bad), $bad, $text, $count);

    echo $text;

    if ($count > 0){
        echo "Bad";
    } else {
        echo "Good";
    }

    return $text;
}

$text = " this is a dirty text test no butt here and no lips ";
badWords($text);
```

Comment: Can even get rid of the `for`, `$text = str_replace($bad, $rep, $text, $count);`.

Comment: why for you can get $count http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf8d0fe930218e23ca7c98b931b304628ee4b38f

Comment: Yeah I didnt want to change his original code too much (so he can see the answer). Its much better to let PHP do the looping though (by padding an array rather than a string)

Comment: Removed the loop in the edited section. Again didnt want to make the original unrecognisable (so the OP isnt sure what part is doing the counting)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. This solution is also case insensitive:

```
<?php

function filter_bad_words($text, $badWords, &$badWordCount)
{
    return str_ireplace($badWords, "***", $text, $badWordCount);
}

$badWordCount;
$badWords = ["terrorists", "obama", "goons"];
$text = "The real terrorists are Obama and his goons.";

print filter_bad_words($text, $badWords, $badWordCount) . "\n";
print "Replacements: {$badWordCount}\n";

if($badWordCount > 0)
    print "Suspected terrorism in text\n";
```

Comment: it's a good example it's look closer to my code ,, im new in web programming plaform i hope stackoverflow community is the school where i can learn from it

Comment: @DocTor if you like my solution better, please pick as best :) My solution works with upper and lower case, and also provides the number of bad words found.